# Why is it ok to satisfy an explicit constructor's argument using member initialisation in a constructor?

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

I'm sorry for the incredibly cryptic title.

I have been reading "More Exceptional C++" by Herb Sutter, and I came across an example of a "counted pointer", I won't paste the entire code, but he uses an explicit constructor with the signature:

```
explicit countedPointer(P* obj): p(new impl(obj) ) {}
```

Further, he declares a class which has a counted Pointer object as a private member of the class, in the constructor of this class, he initialises his counted pointer as so:

```
flagNth(n):pimpl_(new flagNthImpl(n)) {}
```

where, pimpl_ is the counter pointer object, i.e.

```
countedPointer<flagNthImpl>pimpl_;
```

I tried to run this code and inside main.cpp, if I try to do the following I get an error (obviously, since the constructor is explicit)

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    countedPointer<int> cp = new int(5);
}
```

My question is, why is it ok to do this inside the member initialisation list of a constructor instead ? Is the initialisation somehow different from a regular initialisation, and if so, how ?

Thank you!

Comment: `pimpl_(new flagNthImpl(n))` is the same as `countedPointer<int> cp(new int(5))`

Comment: `countedPointer<int> cp = new int(5);` is an assignment, not an initialisation `countedPointer<int> cp(new int(5));` is the same as the class syntax and should work.

Comment: @djgandy That's most definitely **not** an assignment. It's copy initialisation, but it's still **initialisation**.

Comment: Yes a sloppy reading on my part. It is requires an implicit conversion which is unavailable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work for you in `main`:

```
countedPointer<int> cp(new int(5));
```

It's *direct initialisation* and would invoke the constructor normally.

However, you're doing this:

```
countedPointer<int> cp = new int(5);
```

That's *copy initialisation,* and that doesn't work with explicit constructors. To successfully use copy initialisation with an explicit constructor, you'd need this:

```
countedPointer<int> cp = countedPointer<int>(new int(5));
```

Of course, you're generally better off using direct initialisation (as the first example), or direct list initialisation:

```
countedPointer<int> cp{new int(5)};
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So member initialisation of an object inside a constructor is essentially direct initialisation ?

Comment: @rmadhwal Yes, initialisation inside a mem-initializer-list is always direct initialisation or direct list initialisation.